# Не работает тема

Tags: java, android, android-themes

Есть два устройства:
android 5.0.1 lenovo и
android 8.0.0 samsung 
проблема в том, что на samsung не работает тема `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"`
при запуске активности с этой темой приложение вылетает. Посоветуйте что-нибудь. Может быть другую похожую тему

Answer (score 0):

А вы к чему применяете тему? Если к активити, то и не будет работать. Для активити надо что-то типа `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`

Comment: В том то и дело, что работает на другом устройстве

Comment: То, что работает на другом устройстве, совсем не значит, что везде заработает. Все зависит от криворукости и пряморукости разработчиков.